# Detect clicked element on mousedown

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm trying to find a way to get what element is being clicked on when a mousedown behavior is initiated, something that could work similarly to this:

```
function mousedrag(d){
    if(selectedObject == rectangle)
    {
        ...
    }
    else if(selectedObject == circle){
        ...
    }
    else{
        ...
    }
}
```

Please help, and thanks in advance

Comment: `selectedObj` would be `d.target`

Comment: @MinusFour so d.target == circle would work? And what about classes?

Comment: That would depend on what `circle` is and what you want. Do you want to check if `d.target` is an **`instance`** of circle or a rectangle?

Comment: @MinusFour Well, I need to be able to identify the shape type that it is, and then from there the index of the selected object according to a predefined matrix, ie allCircles[2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.nodeName` in your mouse drag:

```
function mousedrag() {
  if (this.nodeName === "circle"){
    // it's a circle
  } else if (this.nodeName === "rect"){
    // it's a rectangle
  }
}
```

Full working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
</style>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 500,
    height = 500,
    radius = 20;

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
//    .origin(function(d) { return d; })
    .on("drag", dragmove);

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 20)
    .attr("cx", 100)
    .attr("cy", 100)
    .call(drag);
    
svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 30)
    .attr("height", 30)
    .attr("x", 200)
    .attr("y", 200)
    .call(drag);

function dragmove() {
  if (this.nodeName === "circle"){
    d3.select(this)
      .attr("cx", d3.event.x)
      .attr("cy",d3.event.y);
  } else if (this.nodeName === "rect"){
    d3.select(this)
      .attr("x", d3.event.x)
      .attr("y",d3.event.y);
  }
}
</script>
</body>
```